# All columns from same table want to get them in tabular form in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this two query's:

```
select CurBalName, CurBalAmount, CurBalDC from Tb_CurBal where curbaldc = 'C'
select CurBalName, CurBalAmount, CurBalDC from Tb_CurBal where curbaldc = 'D'
```

I would like to show them in the tabular form as shown on the image below...

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKff5.jpg)

**Desired result:**

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

Comment: do you mean you want all "rows" in single query, like `where curbaldc in ('D','C')`?

Comment: Actually what you want result?

Comment: actually I want to get the values like name its amount of 'd'| name its amount of 'c' all the two tables above shown in snapshot from single table i need them to be in tabular form

Comment: Records of `C` and `D` in `CurBalC`?

Comment: table includes only c and d type values only its c for credit and d for debit I want it as Trail Balance type. One side with debit values and other side with credit values

Comment: Is there any connection between two groups of data(like ID or something simmilar) or you just want one group on the right and the other on the left ?

Comment: there is nothing common, desire is left side is for all debit entries and right side is for only credit entries from single table. As shown in query also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options:

```
Select case when curbaldc = 'D' then CurBalName
             else null 
        end CurBalName_D
        , case when curbaldc = 'D' then CurBalAmount
             else null 
        end CurBalAmount_D
        , case when curbaldc = 'D' then CurBalDC
             else null 
        end CurBalDC_D
        , case when curbaldc = 'C' then CurBalName
             else null 
        end CurBalName_C
        , case when curbaldc = 'C' then CurBalAmount
             else null 
        end CurBalAmount_C
        , case when curbaldc = 'C' then CurBalDC
             else null 
        end CurBalDC_C
from Tb_CurBal;
```

One more way:

```
select * from 
(select * from Tb_CurBal where curbaldc = 'D') A
full outer join
(select * from Tb_CurBal where curbaldc = 'C') B
on A.curbaldc = B.curbaldc
```

This will work on SQLServer:

```
select A.CurBalName, A.CurBalAmount, A.CurBalDC, 
       B.CurBalName, B.CurBalAmount, B.CurBalDC
from 
(select CurBalName, CurBalAmount, CurBalDC, row_number() over (order by CurBalName) rn
from Tb_CurBal where curbaldc = 'D') A
left join
(select CurBalName, CurBalAmount, CurBalDC, row_number() over (order by CurBalName) rn 
from Tb_CurBal where curbaldc = 'C') B
on A.rn = B.rn
```

Comment: It will show the null values opposite to other side value which will not look nice for presentation. otherwise requirement is the same

Comment: I am desiring that it should not display null values in output rather starts with value of either side in common of both sides like value1 on left side, value1 or right side ..... n values of either side

Comment: Show it in the question. Click edit and insert example.

Comment: [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPo7t.jpg ) actually i desire this thing

Comment: OK I see the picture but add it in the question. Click edit and add the image. Alsoadd an information what database do you us e?

Comment: Hello @GurpreetSingh, I see that the last option was good for you. Please note that if you continue to ask questions in this way you will not have a lot of succes in the future. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: in addition to the above query, can I get the total of the left and right side also in the last

Comment: Please open new question. Add this example and this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac1f3bd51428c72049e2218f0d00af35 Then describe what you want. Try to add as much details as you can and then you wil lhave more people working on it...

Comment: query is same, desired is total of each side of d side and c side

Comment: I uderstand, open a new question because I now do not know how to od it.... And maybe other will...